# Pandas column value compare and filter other column The truth value of a Series is ambiguous Error: a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe and i want to do this operation 
if A ='ad' and C not in ['b','d'] then list [A, B]

```
A      B      C      D
ad     1      b      a
ad     1      b      d
cd     2      c      k
dc     3      k      a
ad     1      c      a
```

here is the code i tried

```
print("\ntest",df.loc[(df["A"] =='ad') & (df["c"] not in ["b","d"]),["A","B"]])
```

the error 
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
tried adding any() that not solved the problem

what is the solution ,i referred something but not gave any solution.

Comment: in `df["c"]`  shouldn't it be capital 'C'? And what do you mean with  "C not in ['b','d']"? you  mean if the element in the C column is not b or d? or if the columns b and d don't have any element 'c'? could you be more clear? and maybe share an example of the expected output ? :)

Comment: `df[(df['A'] == 'ad') & ~(df['C'].isin(["b", "d"]))][["A", "B"]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
df[~df['C'].isin(['b', 'd']) & df['A'].isin(['ad'])][["A", "B"]]
```

*one-liner* will get you the columns *'A'* and *'B'*

Comment: What if i have other more columns that i want to print ,can you check my logic and help how to write that one line logic.

Comment: ( 1 ) df[~df['C'].isin(['b', 'd']) & df['A'].isin(['ad'])][["A", "B"]] if you want A and B *OR*
( 2 ) df[~df['C'].isin(['b', 'd']) & df['A'].isin(['ad'])][["A", "B", "C"]] if you want A, B and C and so on....

Comment: very simple yet accurate answer. it helps a lot.